# How to pin/unpin std::vector to actual, uncompressed hardware memory on Windows?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, prefetch

#### Background

I'm working on some scientific data processing pipeline. It is highly parallelized and performance optimized - the problem is that at one point in the pipeline which uses a lot of memory, CPU usage falls to under 10% despite it being parallelized and containing no critical sections (actually each CPU is going to an under 10% workload state).

[image: Memory allocation]

At this point of the processing, there is no explicit access (writing or reading) of files on the filesystem. The app is shown to have 94GB Committed and a 6.5GB working set (I'm not sure if on windows the working set contains compressed memory or not).

[image: allocation]

It also shows 0 Hard Faults/sec, but I can't see much other reason to have less than 10% of CPU usage during fully parallelized code execution with no critical sections and disk I/O, if it's not something related to either paging or memory compression/decompression.

#### Code

Now, simplified, my data structures and algorithm look something like this:

```
struct Tile {
  struct Datapoint {
    float pos[3];
    float uv[2];
    float col[4];
  };
  struct Cluster {
    std::vector<size_t> indices;
    std::vector<float> weights;
  };
  
  std::vector<Datapoint> datapoints;
  std::vector<Cluster> clusters;
};

std::vector<Tile> tiles;

FillTiles(tiles); // this is not slow and is generating the ~100GB of data in memory

std::vector<float> filtered_data(tiles.size());

// the following is slow
ParallelFor(thread_count, tiles.size(), [&](int i) {
  filtered_data[i] = FilterTile(tiles[i]);
});
```

the ParallelFor I'm using works very well throughout my other code and the `float FilterTile(const Tile& tile)` function has no critical sections, so it only works on the data of Tile (but it's too complex to paste here).

What I'd like to do now is something like this:

```
ParallelFor(thread_count, tiles.size(), [&](int i) {
  Pin(tiles[i+100]); // pseudocode, obviously propper bound checking has to be done.
  filtered_data[i] = FilterTile(tiles[i]);
  Unpin(tiles[i]);
});
```

What `void Pin(const Tile& tile)` would need to do is to tell Windows that it should move the data associated with this tile to uncompressed main memory and leave it there until I call `void Unpin(const Tile& tile)`.

#### Questions

1. How can I request the pinning of the data of `std::vector<Datapoint> datapoints` to uncompressed mainmemory without blocking? I'm for now looking for something that works on Windows 10 and don't necessarily need a portable way of doing this.
2. While `std::vector<Datapoint> datapoints` contains only one chunk of continguous memory, the elements of `std::vector<Cluster> clusters` contain std::vectors themselves that I want to prefetch and pin. I don't assume that there is some out of the box recursive solution for this, so - in case there is a solution for the first question (which I'm absolutely sure there is, since OpenGL drivers for example can do that too) - is there some way of subscribing a callback, so that I can get notified when `std::vector<Cluster> clusters` has been fully pinned, so that I then can iterate over it to request the pinning of `std::vector<size_t> indices` and `std::vector<float> weights` of each Cluster element?
3. How would the implementation of `void Unpin(const Tile& tile)` look like?
4. Bonus question: I'm running on Xeon Gold CPU's with 1MB of L2 cache per core. Most of the tiles are only a couple hundred of KB. So I wonder if additionally to `Pin(tiles[i+100]);` I could also implement `MoveToL2(tiles[i+1]);` to prefetch the data for the next iteration into L2 memory. If so, how could I implement that?

Comment: There is no compression applied to RAM.

Comment: @Mark Ransom on Windows 10 there is

Comment: Link please.  I can see compression being applied as RAM is swapped to disk, but that happens rarely and can actually be faster than not compressing due to the reduced I/O.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Google Windows 10 compressed memory feature (it's possible to deactivate it globally though)

Comment: @user1282931 there is one, but it's very CPU-bound feature (possibly was  introduced for support for VM and upcoming - not quite successful Intel feature for chipset). It is meant to compress unused virtual memory while it's not accessed, essentially it's a RAM swap file

Comment: So I checked it out, and it looks like that Windows 10 feature is just substituting some spare RAM for the normal disk paging.  The CPU is not trying to execute anything from compressed RAM so it will have no effect on the overall system operation except to reduce the RAM available.

Comment: @Mark Ransom exactly, it's basically paging out to compressed ram rather than paging out to disk. And that may very well affect data access latency

Comment: But *any* kind of paging will greatly affect latency.  The solution is to buy enough RAM.

Comment: @Mark Ransom no. I know ahead of time which memory is going to be used (the OS does not) - so all I need to do is to prefetch it from code.

Comment: You are not actually limited by physical memory as you are obviously not swapping. If you did hit memory compression in a bad way, CPU utilization would spike, not stall. That indicates that you most likely misjudged the cause of the slowdown, and should perform some real profiling rather than wild guesses. Profiling in the sense of sampling the process while in the bogus state, and check where each thread got stuck. https://github.com/google/UIforETW is your friend.

Comment: @Ext3h I do see the "Memory Compression" Task being quite busy but yes, it's not saturating CPUs but I don't know anything about the implementation of the Memory Compression, so maybe it has critical sections itself and that's why it's not saturating the CPUs.
and yes - you are right - maybe I end up finding the problem being a different one - but that leaves the question of how to pin and unpin memory using c++ on windows still a valid one.

Comment: It all boils down to latency hiding - and that is a very valid approach in performance optimization.

Comment: VirtualLock / VirtualUnlock. Plenty of questions on SO where that had already been answered.

Comment: @Ext3h what I couldn't find out so far is what happens when calling VirtualLock on paged-out memory. Will it block until the memory is paged in again? if not, is it possible to get a callback or check whether certain memory is indeed in the working set?

Comment: We need more detail on the ParallelFor.  It sounds to me like it's not actually parallelizing in this case even though it works in others.  Perhaps it depends on the compiler proving there's no aliasing, which is easy in some cases and hard in others.  Also, the compiler can probably vectorize the fill, which means it would run even faster.  Ten percent is close to one core out of eight--I strongly suspect this isn't parallelizing as you intended.

Comment: Yes, `VirtualLock` will block until the page is backed by memory. But you should be careful about using it at all, it does have a significant overhead.

Comment: in that case it's not what I need. There's no use to call it ahead of time if it's gonna block until it's actually paged in.